# How to control or Block attachment URLs?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

We are working for a site and almost every post having one extra url from image[image] attachment and webmaster considering duplicate content of my site.

Please see attachment and also tell me that's why my URL is not showing completely in SERP and showing in category ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the work of **the_attachment_link** template tag.

Have a look here for the documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link

You should be able to edit your theme files and remove these links (or simply comment them out)

Example:

```
 <?php the_attachment_link( $id, $fullsize, $deprecated, $permalink ); ?>
```

Change to:

```
 <?php /* the_attachment_link( $id, $fullsize, $deprecated, $permalink ); */ ?>
```